# Is there any way to dynamically choose font-size depending on element size

Tags: html, css

I just found out that the maximum possible email length is 254 characters.

I decided to see how my page looks with just a 50 character email address (there is 'logged as user@wherever.com' notice), and this length breaks the look of all the top of the site.

Is there any way so set the font of this notice in a such way, so it always be one size despite of email length?

Comment: With javascript plugins yes. See http://fittextjs.com/. Slabtext does something similar, but I think you want fittext. I've used it for responsive sites, but I think it can solve your problem. http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/

Comment: @Leeish I would have upvoted that answer

Comment: actually, I can do this with ruby, coz app is on rails. But I thought that may be there is CSS feature. So what kind of formula do I need? Font-size=email.length*1/x? And x should be..?

Comment: You will probs have to set the size manually with media queries. I don't know if LESS/ SCSS might be of any help.